# Why am I getting an encoding error when I compare a cell to a String?

Tags: python

The datetime object cells update, 
However, although print(cell.value) works when I iterate through every cell, they cell.value is not updating when I use an If statement to compare cell.value directly to a String.

Additionally, when I even try to compile the code whilst comparing directly to a string object I get an encoding error from PythonWin, assigning a string to a variable however does not give me an error, but the cells which contain the string I want are no longer found and nothing is printed anyways.  Printing cell.encoding for every cell shows utf-8 encoding, I am on Python 3.

```
 a = datetime.datetime.strptime(oldDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pathz, read_only=False)
    ws = wb.active
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                #This works fine v
                if cell.value == a:
                    print("Found datetime cell")
                    cell.value = newDate

                #This does not work v        
                if cell.value == "Hello":
                    print("Found string cell")
                    cell.value = "Goodbye"

    wb.save(pathz)
```

Comment: Can you add, right before the call that fails: `print("Cell: %s Type: %s" % (cell.value, type(cell.value))` Also, please [edit] your question to include what `a` is?

Comment: @TemporalWolf add what a =.  Where do you mean to add the print("Cell: %s Type: %s" % (cell.value, type(cell.value)) ?

Comment: Right above `if cell.value == "Hello":` That way, when it fails, you'll have a print out of what the cell that it failed on contains.

Comment: Will test it now and get back to you asap.  Note that I am not given actual errors or exceptions when i run my code, it simply does not do the action I ask it to.

Comment: `I get an encoding error from PythonWin`? what error. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I get an encoding error due to a unicode dash in the cells I am modifiying.  My program does not recognize it as a regular string.

Comment: @TemporalWolf 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 6725: ordinal not in range(256). Please add desired source encoding as first line of file, eg #-*-coding: mbcs-*-

Comment: looks the dash is precisely the problem, how does one go about fixing it? I am not able to save my file with the new dash in my code right now due to the encoding issue